# Why is the 'System' process listening on port 443?

Tags: windows

I am having problems starting my Apache server, because port 443 is already in use.

It turns out, the system process (PID 4) uses the port 443. I don't have IIS installed, the services.msc shows (predictably) no Exchange server running, nor WWW-Services, nor IIS. I have no idea how to find out what service uses that port, short of just disabling each service one after the other, and I am not even sure that would help.

I would be grateful if someone could point me towards how I can get my SSL port back, thank you :)

P.S.: Of course "just switch Apache to another port for SSL" would solve the problem of not being able to start Apache. But I'd still like to know what is so insistent about hogging port 443. :)

---

I by now took the 'hard route' and disabled services one after the other. It turned out that the "Routing and RAS" service was the culprit.

Thank you all for the valuable input and the new tools in the combat against "WTF does my system do now?".

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/121901  You could use any of the answers given to help you determine which service is opening port 443.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I am unable (or just too stupid) to find out which service exactely holds the port open, I cannot use "SC Config Servicename Type= own" for a lag of Servicename.
Netstat's various incantation point me at the System process, as said, just like TCPView did. "Stacks", as for PE, don't work on Win7 apparently and as I do not look at a svchost.exe instance, I do not have a "Service" column on the TCP/IP tab.
Skype is not at fault, nor do I have any other VoIP or P2P software running.
But the other question you linked was enlightening to me; thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the info! For me it was "Routing and Remote Access" service that had binded port 443 also.

Comment: Man, the amount of answers not even trying to answer the question is incredible. So is the amount of misinformation. If PID 4 is listening, it’s `http.sys`. Always. Luckily, [there’s already an answer on how to gain insight](https://superuser.com/a/726975/219095).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run the following from an elevated command prompt:

```
netstat -ab
```

Comment: I am a bit surprised. Anything else showed just "the system process" as culprit. This command now claims that it -is- a svchost.exe that holds this port. :|
How comes PE / 'other' netstat calls subsumed it under the System process? (Although the port is still shown as held by PID 4 / System.) How can I inspect further? :(

Comment: not sure but run PE elevated maybe!

Comment: also the following may give you more insight                      wmic process > test.txt

Comment: I did run process explorer as administrator -- and still the port shows up as claimed by "System"; not really much more intel available there :|
By now I think it'll be something really stupid I unwittingly did ;)

Comment: did u run the wmic command and look at the test.txt file it will give u more insight I think!

Comment: ... nice.
I did not know that command either. Thank you!

Comment: the power that wmic can provide is quite outstanding, if you can think about it wmic can do it (at least within the windows envrio)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, under the line with 0.0.0.0:443 I just get **Can not obtain ownership information**.

Answer (score 33):

I bet it's Skype. Uncheck the checkbox shown below if you have it installed.

[image]

Comment: +1. Other VoIP clients (and other software like P2P file transfer apps) will listen on ports 80 and 443 if they find nothing else there, though Skype is the most common "offender". I'm not sure why Skype would be showing up as a system owned process though.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not Skype; nor other VoIP clients (none installed) nor P2P etc. etc.
I checked that and it is not only "a system owned process", it is "the system process" (PID 4)

Comment: Oddly, I had the same issue as the OP - 443 was taken by svchost.. and yet, turning off Skype fixed it.

Comment: Had this problem.  Followed these instructions and figured out it was Skype: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-check-and-identify-which-application-is-listening-or-opening-port-80-and-443-on-windows/

Comment: Just for clarity's sake: If your port is held by svchost and plainly visible in Process Explorer, it was not the same problem I had. Hence my insistence on making clear that the process with the name "System" seemed to own the port.

Comment: For me, it was skype as well.  Generally, I guess I usually start my app first and Skype second which ends up working.

Comment: This one solved my issue.

Answer (score 27):

First off, I will answer this question directly and anyone reading this can ignore any answers talking about 3rd-party, non-Microsoft applications using the System Process.

1. The **System** process is listed as **PID 4** on every modern-day Windows system. It is for kernel-mode access. This rules out most 3rd-party web products like Apache.
2. Since the inception of WinRM (Windows Remote Management), the **HTTP** service (**%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\http.sys**) has been a standard part of Windows (Vista and later / Server 2008 and later). http.sys runs under the **System** process (**PID 4**).
3. Other Microsoft-developed software may also use the %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\**http.sys** under the System process like **IIS**, **SQL Reporting Services**, and **Microsoft Web Deployment Service** (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597817)...
4. WinRM 1.0 default ports were:
   HTTP = 80
   HTTPS = 443
   WinRM 2.0 and greater default ports are:
   HTTP = 5985
   HTTPS = 5986
   Check with the following commands:
   **Winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener**
   **Winrm get http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/config**

Troubleshooting steps:

## Get the process number of the port that you are looking for (443 in this case):

...from a non-mapped drive of Windows to avoid "Access Denied":
**netstat -aon | find ":443"**
Output should look like the following for the **System** process:
C:>netstat -ano |find ":443"
TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
TCP    [::]:443               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
The last column is the PID (4).

5. Running **tasklist** to find out what is running in the process proves unhelpful:
   tasklist /SVC /FI "PID eq 4"
   tasklist /m /FI "PID eq 4"
6. Look in the registry for the HTTP service:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters\UrlAclInfo
   There will be a list of URLs (with the port numbers) which can lead you to which application is running and holding which ports:
   http:// +:5985/wsman/ --> **WinRM**
   https:// +:5986/wsman/ --> **WinRM**
   http:// +:80/Reports/ --> **SQL Reporting Server**
   http:// +:80/ReportServer/ --> **SQL Reporting Server**
   https:// server_fqdn:443/Reports/ --> **SQL Reporting Server**
   https:// server_fqdn:443/ReportsServer/ --> **SQL Reporting Server**
   http://* :2869/ --> **Simple Service Discovery Protocol service (SSDPSRV)**
   http://* :5357/ --> **Web Services Dynamic Discovery (WS-Discovery)**
   https://* :5358/ --> **Web Services Dynamic Discovery (WS-Discovery)**

You can then find the corresponding service on the system and stop it and see that wanted port is released by confirming with another **netstat -aon | find ":443"** command.

Comment: Regarding point 6, how do we find the process listening for those ports?

Comment: This is by far(as of my reading) the most valuable answer. However, it doesn't resolve my problem. I'm having the problem on a Windows Server 2016 and the above step 6 shows `https://+:443/sra_{BA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0ADCD75}/` on my server. The GUID BA1959xxx indicates an SSTP server. But I'm sure I'm running at least another process listening on 443 other than the SSTP server. Anyway, I vote up for you.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I looked up **http.sys**, and found the command `netsh http show servicestate` which dumps a lot of data including the actual current listening URLs. It solved my problem of "why is SYSTEM listening on port X", it could help others.

Comment: I found vmware client was using the port 443

Comment: Step 6 is very valuable. In my case what I did was to edit ALL the registries using :443 to something like :4443 (another port) and restarted the system. After that I was able to start my IIS website

Answer (score 13):

I had the problem that port 443 was used by "system" with PID 4 on my Windows 7 machine. The solution for me was to delete a "Incoming Connection" (VPN) which existed in the network connections folder.

It seems that I created it and forgot to delete it after usage...

Comment: Yep, had the same issue on Windows 8.1.

Comment: just did that win7. It stopped listening on TCP 443 though still is listening on UDP port 443 though that may be good enough.

Comment: I had this issue on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64. Took me a while to find your post and I'm surprised at the official answer for this question, since it doesn't actually answer the question at all. Thank you!

Comment: It worked for me when instead of deleting the "Incoming Connection" (I don't remember how to create it again if I need it again) I unchecked `[_] Allow other computers to connect to this one` under Network and Sharing Center, Adapter Configuration, Incoming Connection, Properties.

Answer (score 10):

Often this is the VMware host agent service (required for VM-host-to-guest communication) - `vmware-hostd.exe`.

A good way to find out what sub process svchost.exe is running is to use Sysinternals' [Process Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer).

[image]

Comment: If you indeed have VMware Workstation installed, check under Edit -> Preferences -> Shared VMs. You probably have VM sharing enabled and default port is 443. You can disable sharing, change port and enable it back or just leave it disabled if you don't need it.

Comment: @gronostaj Thank you so much i just spend 3 hours trying to find this :(

Comment: Note you must run VMware Workstation as an administrator, otherwise the "Disable Sharing" button will be grayed out.

Answer (score 8):

I faced similar issues with routing 443 requests to my WAS server. Based on the recommendations in this question, this is what I did:

1. From elevated cmd prompt ran `netstat -a -n -o | findstr 443`
2. Identified the PID of the process listening on 443
3. Used Process Explorer to identify the process from the PID.
4. In my case the application listening was `vmwarehostd.exe`
5. Stopped the VMware Workstation server from `services.msc`. Restarted by WAS server.

And all the 443 requests came to 443 happily ever after.

PS: I had already uninstalled skype which came builtin with my Windows 8 installation. Routing and remote access service was disabled in my machine.

Comment: -1  His was PID 4 it was much harder. You write "Used process explorer to identify the process from the pid."   <-- Yours wasn't PID 4 e.g. svchost or something like that. Yours was some 3rd party exe.  You could've just used task manager! If you're not showing the column already then view..choose column  But you were lucky your PID wasn't PID 4. I don't know if process explorer could help there though task manager can't. But certainly in your case simple task manager would've done it.

Answer (score 6):

If it is a process started by a service, `netstat -ab` won't help.

In this case try `netstat -ao | find /i "443"` in an administrator command line. This will give you an output like this:

```
    TCP   0.0.0.0:443   your_hostname:0   LISTENING   PID
```

Then type `tasklist | find /i "<PID>"` in another administrator command prompt.

In my case the PID was 2912 and my command was:

```
tasklist | find /i "2912"
```

The output of my command was:

```
vmware-hostd.exe   2912 Services   0   39 856 K
```

Wow, I have even forgotten that I installed VMware to check a functionality...

Comment: For me this was PID 4... being System. Still no clue :)

Comment: PID 4 usually means a native Microsoft based Windows service, which means kernel level. Try stopping services one by one, and check if it solved the problem. Disable the service/uninstall the feature that @Wouter caused the issue. Usual services are: `Routing and RAS`, anything noting `IIS` or `World Wide Puplishing`, `Exchange` `Windows Sync Share`, `Web Deployment Agent Service`, `SQL Server Reporting Services`, `File Server Storage Reports Manager` and similar.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the DTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator) process to use the 443 port. In particular, I activated WS-AT in DTC, and it was using 443 port.

In general, I understand that when the System process (PID 4) uses the 443/HTTPS port, it is an internal process of Windows (in my case DTC, but I think can be also another process), if it's not an IIS website using it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was DataManager from F5 Networks which uses Tomcat 6 internally to serve its web pages. I forgot to uninstall that app. Bad design decision, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Using `netstat -ao | find ":443"`, I found out that port 443 is being used by PID 4, which was the System process. This happened to me twice on Windows Server 2012, and it was due to one of the following reasons:

1. IIS was running, listed as "World Wide Web Publishing Service" in Services, which I stopped.
2. The Work Folders feature installed, so I uninstalled it.

This might not be a solution for everyone, but it may help some.

Comment: This answer does not really add any new information that wasn't already in the answers submitted by elbedoit or tonyr

Comment: I specifically added this answer because uninstalling the Work Folders feature worked for me, and thus it is a potential solution to the problem as it it written. Should I present this information in a comment instead?

Comment: I had the same issue as stated in the question, and tonyr's answer did not work for me. elbedoit's answer does not help when you have PID 4 (as stated in the question); are you going to randomly stop/restart system processes to fix the issue?

Comment: Still does not change the fact this answer seems incomplete and seems to repeat the same information that already exists in existing questions.

Comment: No other answer mentions uninstalling the Work Folders feature, which is a solution to the question. I repeated the information from the other answer(s) to help others with the same issue identify if this solution may work for them (i.e., check to make sure PID is 4). If the PID is not 4, this answer will definitely not help. How is this answer any more incomplete then doener's or tonyr's answers? Please suggest how I can communicate my solution better.

Comment: Yes! It was also the Work Folders feature for me! Thanks a lot for mentioning this. It is indeed an equaly valid answer as mentioning Skype or any other service...

Answer (score 1):

For me, after the Windows Server 2016 update, Apache 443 could not start with usual event listed.

I found the culprit to be "Windows Sync Share" Service (SyncShareSvc). I disabled and was able to start Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Open `services` from the start menu search and find and stop the `Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol Service`. Based on other answers I could infer that it's the underlying system service that sits on this port. I thought it's needed for VPNs but I could use a 3rd party one just fine with its own app. If it solved the problem feel free to disable it. It'll cause its dependencies to not run as well, which are `Remote Access Connection Manager` and `Routing and Remote Access`.

It was running after a completed Windows 10 update in 2022 April, I could use the port just fine just before that.

This likely happens because I used the allow incoming connections in the network connections window to set up Windows users (without their profiles) to create users for file sharing on the LAN (Samba). This option was left in, creating a VPN server I believe.

[image: If you accepting incoming connections]

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the VPN functionality in Windows 8 (probably the same for Windows 7) used port 443.

Additionally, my port closed up again by PMB.exe (Pando Media Booster).

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the McAfee EPO agent listening on port 80. I had to go through several painful hoops to get it changed. https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB67605

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows Server 2019, I solved it by running this PS.

```
Stop-Service -Name KPSSVC
```

It ran as process 4 (SYSTEM process) under Network Service privileges.
Running

```
netstat -ab
```

did not help. It displayed 'Can not obtain ownership information'.

After stopping the service, netstat -aon | findstr ":443" does not show the entry anymore. Found out by literary stopping each service one by one.

KDC Proxy Server service (KPS) - KDC Proxy Server service runs on edge servers to proxy Kerberos protocol messages to domain controllers on the corporate network.

Another culprit could be Windows Admin Center (ServerManagementGateway)

Answer (score -1):

Wireshark will tell you the details. http://www.wireshark.org/
Or TCP Monitor: http://www.itsamples.com/tcp-monitor.html

That'll help.

Comment: tcp-monitor unfortunately could not really help me at all; as for wireshark -- I was unable to generate / capture packets directed at port 443. :(

Comment: The only remaining option is Process Explorer (sysinternals) it'll show you proceses with ports.
Wireshark is one of the top products in this line, but I can't comprehend why it didn't work for you :s (Did you install the WinPCAP capture driver?)

Comment: Very late response, sorry. But I could not get anything to log because there apparrently just was no traffic to sniff. At least so I presume.

Comment: -1 Wireshark will not show you anything that might help identify what is on the port.. unless there are packets going to the port  And even then, you should provide more info e.g. that the person should then ping the IP and try to find out what that IP is.

Answer (score -1):

If you have some sort of Virtual LAN driver (like OpenVM, VMware, etc..) - make sure you 'release' the port before giving it to something else...

Just a quick side-hint ;)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same trouble while trying to install a VMware update.  I tracked it down to Skype. The new client defaults to 443.

Comment: This just a repeat of an existing answer.  Please upvote existing answers rather than reposting.

Comment: @Chenmunka Maybe he didn't read it