# Which of these Windows services is most likely responsible for outgoing port 53 (DNS) traffic?

Tags: windows-7, dns, firewall, port, services

Working on a Windows 7 system that has network traffic very locked down.  The system is not running any servers.  Besides Windows itself, and an antivirus tool, it does not have any software that automatically performs internet activity.

After the system in booted or returned from a sleep state, I'm sometimes receiving notifications of attempted outgoing port 53 (DNS) traffic.

The traffic is coming from Host Process for Windows Services (svchost.exe), which at the time of the traffic is running one of the following groups of services:

1. Appinfo,EapHost,gpsvc,IKEEXT,iphlpsvc,LanmanServer,MMCSS,ProfSvc,Schedule,SENS,ShellHWDetection,Themes,Winmgmt,wuauserv
2. EventSystem,fdPHost,FontCache,netprofm,nsi,WdiServiceHost,WinHttpAutoProxySvc

For each of those 2 groups, which are the most likely services that are actually sending the port 53 traffic?

---

Edit: After writing this question, I found: [Is there a way to determine which service (in svchost.exe) does an outgoing connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/121901/is-there-a-way-to-determine-which-service-in-svchost-exe-does-an-outgoing-conn)

It was missing a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) tag, so it didn't appear in any of my searches.  (To help others, I just added a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) tag to it.)

I can likely use the techniques described in that answer to eventually figure this out, but as this is a sporadic issue, if anyone already knows the answer to this question, they will save me a bunch of time by answering it.  Thanks!

Comment: Seems odd that _any_ of them would cause this traffic, since usually it's the job of the Dnscache service to handle all DNS requests...

Comment: @user1686 I agree.  But at least one service from group #1 and at least one service from group #2 is trying to send out packets on port 53, according to the logs.